# Import F# block of code into C# application

Tags: c#, f#

I was looking for solution to import F# block of code into C# application (in order to gain calculation speed of some operations I have). Therefore I install FSharpx.Core to my C# solution in MS Visual Studio Express 2013.
And that's it...don't know how to continue :-)

Can someone help me with some simple code - e.g. when I click a button in the form, to subtract variable v1 and v2.

**Form1.cs**

```
...
private void buttonCalcVars_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int sum = CallFSharpFunction(1,2);
}

// This should be some F# block of code
private int CallFSharpFunction(int a, int b)
{
   let v1 = a;
   let v2 = b;
   // do some calculations

   return result;
}
...
```

Hope this is possible,
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you could simply add an F# project to your solution (as a DLL) and reference it in your C# project. Then you should be able to call the F# methods from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Before using F # one wonders, can you use an F # function in applications written in c #.
Become familiar with functional language F # you can, for example, at this address: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc164244.aspx
But here, in my opinion, F # functional language is good for writing various mathematical functions (excuse my tautology), but why take the bread from the object-oriented languages, why put unintelligible code to work with WinForms or WebForms controls pages in F #? Because I immediately wondered how to invoke a function from F # assemblies. Just want to say that because there are difficulties in functional languages with tipizaciâmi when writing code, in the case of using F # functions from C # assemblies these difficulties only increase. Get down to business.
Create a project that includes, for example, the C # console application and an F # Assembly.
F # in the Assembly we need one file MyFunctions. fs. Here we describe some of the features that we believe it is easier for us to write at a functional language. For example, even if it is the translation function array bitmap images from RGB to YCbCr color space (this is just an example). Entry in F # can be roughly this:

```
open System
let RGB_to_YCbCr (r : double,g : double,b : double) = 
    let y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b in
    let Cb = (-0.1687) * r - 0.3313 * g + 0.5 * b + 128.0 in
    let Cr = 0.5 * r - 0.4187 * g - 0.0813 * b + 128.0 in
    (y,Cb,Cr);

let RGB_to_YCbCr_v (v : _ array) = 
    RGB_to_YCbCr (v.[0], v.[1], v.[2]);
let Process (image : _ array)  = 
    let lenght = Array.length image in
    let imageYCbCr = Array.create lenght (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) in
    for index = 0 to lenght - 1 do
        imageYCbCr.[index] &lt;- RGB_to_YCbCr_v (image.[index])
    done
    imageYCbCr
```

After Assembly, we can see that access to features not just have weird views the namespace, and how to use them is not clear. See the location of the functions in the Assembly we can using Reflector.
In order to describe the namespace and the class you need to add the following line immediately after #light:
module FSharp.Sample.MyFunctions
That said, the fact that all the functions written below will contain the class MyFunctions fsharp.Core namespace.
After the project again, we will see that in the Assembly have a clear the fsharp.Core namespace Sample that has the class MyFunctions static methods, which we have described above.
Read more in our console application, we set the Reference to the Assembly the fsharp.core Sample is the name of my Assembly to F # and the fsharp.core -in order to use types (classes) of the F # type Triple. And write the following code:

```
using System;
using FSharp.Sample;
namespace CSharp.Sample.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double[][] image = new double[1000][];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i &lt; 1000; i ++ )
            {
                image[i] = new double[3];
                image[i][0] = rand.Next();
                image[i][1] = rand.Next();
                image[i][2] = rand.Next();
            }
            foreach (var doubles in MyFunctions.Process(image))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(doubles);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Where initially we specify to use the fsharp.Core namespace. In the code we generate an array of data and pass it to the function MyFunction. Process, which converts it to the chosen algorithm. We are returned as an array of data types "in Microsoft fsharp.core.. Tuple'3".